# Hiding a column based on more than 2 parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i have columns with imperial values and columns with metric values. i want to hide one or the other based on which region a customer may be from but also if they are part of the company or not. So example if person.value = "Employee" then show imperial and metric but if person.value = "Customer" then CustomerRegion.Value = "Europe" , would be shown metric and  CustomerRegion.Value = "North America" would be shown imperial. what would i use to construct an expression to hide one or the other and what would be the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use an IIF statement and add the logic for the various possibilities by nesting multiple IIFs inside each other.

Since you always want to show Imperial to Employees, I would make that the first part of the IIF. For showing and hiding, one column would have one expression while the other would have the same with the TRUEs and FALSEs reversed.

### Imperial Hide:

```
=IIF(PARAMETERS!person.value = "Employee", False, 
 IIF(PARAMETERS!person.value = "Customer AND PARAMETERS!CustomerRegion.Value = "North America", False,
 IIF(PARAMETERS!person.value = "Customer AND (PARAMETERS!CustomerRegion.Value = "Europe" OR PARAMETERS!CustomerRegion.Value = "Asia"), True, True))
```

Swap the TRUE and FALSE for the Metric column.

Instead of hiding one of the columns, why not use the expression to determine which data to show in a single column? Instead of **TRUE** or **FALSE**, you could use the **IMPERIAL** or **METRIC** fields.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies Hannover, I've used your answer as a template for mine.

A SWITCH statement would be a better option here IMHO. IIF evaluates all parts of the expression which can be slower whereas SWITCH stops at the first expression that returns TRUE. If more conditions need to be added, nesting IIF's quickly gets messy.

The SWITCH version would be slightly cleaner but definitely more extensible.

Imperial would be

```
=SWITCH(
    Parameters!Person.Value = "Employee", False,
    Parameters!Person.Value = "Employee" AND Parameters!CustomerRegion.Value = "Europe", True,
    Parameters!Person.Value = "Employee" AND Parameters!CustomerRegion.Value = "North America", False,
True, False)
```

The last pair of expressions act like an ELSE, it will always return true. Here I set the return to False so by default the column would be shown (Hidden = False)

The metric column would just be the opposite except you would probably want to leave the last pair (the True, False at the end) so the metric column is also shown by default.

This could be made even simpler assuming you only ever have Employee and Customer for person.value as you would not have to check it past the first expression. You can also add multiple checks for regions in a nice consice way rather than put them on separate lines, although you could do this with the IIF answer too..

Something like this.

```
=SWITCH(
    Parameters!Person.Value = "Employee", False,
    Parameters!CustomerRegion.Value = "Europe", True,
    "North America Asia Somewhere Else".ToLower.Contains(Parameters!CustomerRegion.Value.ToString.ToLower), False,
True, False)
```

I've used ToLower to make the comparison case insensitive but you could exclude that if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the insightful answers guys. They all work and give the desired result but i have chosen to go with the "Switch" Statement

I Had structured it in this way for the metric column;

=SWITCH(Parameters!Person.Value = "Employee", False, Parameters!CustomerRegion.value = "North America", True)

And i just changed CustomerRegion.value to "Europe" for the imperial columns. It worked just fine this way. Hope this helps :)